# Fixing syntax errors

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to get the following code to work

```
if ready = True:
```

but it says there is a syntax error, and points to the `=`. How can I fix this?

Comment: try `ready == True`. Its a condition, not an assignment.

Comment: Also, just `if result:` is enough for booleans.

Comment: Go through this: 
 https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/python_basic_operators.htm

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
if ready == True:
```

as you want to compare (`==`) not assign (`=`), you can also alternatively write:

```
if ready:
```

Answer (score 1):

To check you should use `==`:

```
if ready == True:
    pass
```

but in this case - where you compare to True, pythonic way is to write just:

```
if ready:
    pass
```

In opposite while checking if is False you may write:

```
if not ready:
    pass
```

In any other cases use:

```
if number == 123:
    pass
```